# Accessing a java map in a .jsp file

Tags: jsp, java-8

I have injected a map, say `myMap<X,Y>` into my **.jsp** file and I want to access a particular key if it is present, say **x**. Here **X** is an enum and **Y** is a java class.

I tried doing:

1. `<c:set var = "xx" value="${myMap[X.x]}" />`
2. `${myMap.get(X.x)}`
3. `${myMap.get(x)}`

but none of it works. I also tried printing the complete map through jsp:
`"${myMap}"` and the correct map is getting printed.

Need some help on how to proceed with this.

Comment: You have to get an understanding of how to use JSP first. There is a script syntax you have to use like `<% %>` between which you can access java variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am aware that scriptlets are used in jsp to write java code, but unfortunately, I am not allowed to use these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question so that it might help others in the future.

I had not imported the file for the enum hence it was not accessible. Doing `<%@ page import="packageName.className">` helped me fix the issue.

Thanks!